# IIS Recompile ASP NET websites

Tags: asp.net, iis, compiler-construction, web

I was talking with a friend about what IIS does when you put a new file inside a virtual directory.

He told me that IIS recompile the entire website when you put a file anywhere in the website, I think it just happens (if happen) when you put a file inside your Bins folder.

The conversation comes because a website in the company is use to upload files but the files are save inside a folder name "Letters" in our website, my friend says that every time someone upload a file IIS will recompile the entire website. Is he correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easy enough to test.  Start watching the JIT compile counters on the web server... Browser around, then drop a file in it to see the counters show.

Comment: run perfmon.  Then add the .NET CLR Jit counters to your graph.  If your app uses anonymous types or anonymous methods it's going to jump all over the place.  Regardless, it will jump when the site does a recompile.

Comment: fine, i did the test and "% Time in Jit" Always jump when i put or remove a file in my BIN folder, if i put or remove the file in other folder nothing happens... thanks

Answer (score 2):

It only recompiles when you add code that needs to be compiled.  I.e. adding new classes to App_Code.  It doesnt recompile when you simply save an image or text file to the website.

Comment: Not exactly true.  There is this little thing called Just In Time compiling.  Just by running certain code you can cause it to recompile (anonymous types is a biggie)

Comment: So what is the best way when small changes have come. Need to publish whole website again ? Or any tricky method out there to recompile whole website from IIS itself?

Answer (score 1):

I think ASP.NET only re-starts and re-compiles the whole site when bin assemblies, App_Code or global.asax are changed.

See [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/davidebb/archive/2009/04/15/a-new-flag-to-optimize-asp-net-compilation-behavior.aspx) for details of a new flag to optimize ASP.NET compilation behavior.

Adding files to a folder within the virtual directory should not lead to a re-compile (unless the folder is 'bin' or 'app_code'!)

Answer (score 1):

There is a setting in the machine.config numRecompilesBeforeApprestart which indicates the number of file changes that can occurr before the application will restart. The default is 15.

In non production environments, I usually set this much higher so you can modify aspx pages on the fly without causing the entire app to restart.

This might be what your friend is talking about.

Comment: yeah but can i upload things suchs as pictures or documents inside a folder and nothing will happens??

Answer (score 0):

Definitely depends on your version because:
There's also a new hotfix that lets you optimize compilation so IIS recompiles less often, but I'm not sure when exactly.

I THINK it used to be that new markup won't trigger a recompile if you don't navigate to it (and instead navigate to another markup file), and bin/dll/assembly files will always trigger.

Answer (score 0):

Recycle the application pool. In powershell:

```
$AppPoolName = 'NameOfApp'

$AppPool = Get-ChildItem iis:\apppools | where { $_.Name -eq $AppPoolName}

Restart-WebAppPool $AppPool
```

This will force code to recompile.

Comment: Recycling the app pool does not seem to cause recompile